# ChartJS X-Axis Time Scale Do Not Display Each Element

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js

In graphs with a lot of datapoints the amount of ticks on the X-axis becomes so overwhelming that it's impossible to read. Is there a way to instruct ChartJS to not render each label element on the X-Axis but for instance only the first of each month?

I have tried using a `category` type instead of `time` and only filling in the labels for the first of the month but then there is also no label for when you hover over a certain datapoint which makes it impossible to determine what day it is, making it unfit for my requirements.

[image: Example Graph]

Comment: Which version of chart.js are you using? The labelling algorithm was significantly improved in recent releases to avoid this kind of problem. The current version is 2.8.0.